# how to freez GUI while a process is running

Tags: swing

I have a treatement that lasts for few secondes , i was wondering to how wilingly freez the gui while the treatement is activated .
I looked for the anwer however every one seems so want to unfreez the GUI.

Answer (score 3):

Execute the operation on the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread), e.g. using `SwingUtilities#invokeAndWait`

Note that a more user-friendly solution could be to show a progress dialog to the user and performing the work in the background. The progress dialog (when modal) does not allow the user to do anything with the UI but your application isn't/doesn't look frozen.

I, as a user, would be annoyed with a frozen UI.